# freeze app when get data from online sql server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, freeze

my app using sql server is located on a server . my problem is a when using this app ، freeze app when get data from server ! 
What is your proposed solution?

Comment: You should provide a little bit of code, we can't just guess the solutions for you. Also, have you tried anythings ? Maybe provide us few of your tests to check where you gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're executing your database query from the UI thread. Perhaps, the query is being executed in a button "click" action handler?

The UI thread is a thread where UI message loop is running and processing UI events (things like button clicks, window resize etc.). If you perform a long running task in the UI thread it will prevent all other UI messages being processed until the task is finished. As a result the UI will look frozen.

Database calls are fairly slow and it's a good idea to execute them outside of the UI thread. One solution is to spin a new thread, providing a callback method to be called once the query execution was completted.

A better approach is to use async/await. You'll have to define an async method that performs a DB call. And then await for that method in your UI thread.

Please show us how you fetch the data from a database and we'll give you more details on how to implement it without blocking the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info here's general advice:

Execute your query on a thread (use a Task if modern), then when thread gets it's data back invoke back on main/UI thread.  This will prevent your UI from locking up while querying for data.

You might also want to start a 'spinner' or a 'loading' indicator of some sort on the UI thread so the user knows to wait and doesn't go click-crazy trying to load the data again and again...

Also be sure to include some error handling in your query thread so if things go bad you can recover and alert (messagebox, write to log, whatever you need to do).